# Perl: execute another program with a copy of STDIN

Tags: perl, stdin

I have a Perl CGI script that redirects to other Perl CGI scripts. Which script is redirected to, depends on the contents of data posted with "POST".

So my redirect script reads `STDIN`:

```
read( STDIN, $buffer, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'} );
```

examines the posted data, then redirects to another CGI script:

```
`run /bin/anotherscript.cgi`
```

This script then needs the original posted data so it also reads `STDIN`. But by then it's empty since it has already been read. Now I know that one solution would be to write the original contents to a file, then use this file as input for the second script:

```
read( STDIN, $buffer, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'} );

open( DATA, ">in.txt" );
print DATA $buffer;
close( DATA );

`run /bin/anotherscript.cgi < in.txt`
```

Now the problem with this is that this is on a website with many users. So I would need to create unique filenames, and make sure everything is nicely cleaned up afterwards. The potential to make a mess of things, is big.

So I was wondering if there's another way to do this? Can I "push" data back to STDIN? Or is there a more direct way to pipe data to the new script?

Comment: See [IPC::Open3](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Open3) or [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way:

```perl
use IPC::Run qw( run );

run [ "run", "/bin/anotherscript.cgi" ], '<', \$buf;
```